# Setting write permissions for folders while creating a package with MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy, nant

I'm using MSDeploy to create an artefact as a build step in NAnt. This particular build step is called on successful compilation. The artefact is then used to for deployment.

Here is the step specified in my build file.

```
  <target name="BuildMsDeployPackage" depends="StageForMsDeployPackaging">
    <exec program="${msdeploy.exe}"
          workingdir="${buildDirectory}"
          verbose="true"
          commandline="-verb:sync 
                      -source:iisapp=${packagingDirectory} 
                      -dest:package=${publishDirectory}\${webapp.artifact.zip}"/>
```

The `source` here is my my web project.

I want to be able to set specify write access to a couple of folders in the package that is created. Is this possible? I know that there is a `setAcl` provider for this specific purpose, but can this be used while creating a package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`manifest` provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569104%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) to include multiple providers in a sync, which will work with the package:

```
msdeploy verb:sync -source:manifest=manifest.xml -dest:package=package.zip
msdeploy verb:sync -source:package=package.zip -dest:auto,computerName=...
```

Then `manifest.xml` is:

```
<multipleAcls>
    <iisApp path="local iis app or path" />
    <setAcl path="remote iis site name/relative path1" setAclAccess="Write" />
    <setAcl path="remote iis site name/relative path2" setAclAccess="Read" />
</multipleAcls>
```

You can use [parameters or replace statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) on the dest:package call to avoid having to dynamically generate the manifest, and you can use similar statements on the deploy call to change which site/path you're deploying to. You can set your dest to a different manifest file as an alternative solution to the latter problem.